# Translate Animation speed of sliding in from bottom

Tags: android, android-webview, android-animation

Good day,

I'm trying to implement an `Animation` that slides in a `WebView` from below onto my screen.
Here's the code of my animation xml file:

**slide_in_from_bottom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
       android:duration="700"/>
 </set>
```

Here is where I ask my `WebView` to slide in:

```
        Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom);
        slideIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Log.d("animation", "started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("animation", "stopped");
            }
        });
        webView.startAnimation(slideIn);
```

This works fine, but the problem is that my `WebView` does not always have the same size. This causes it to slide in really fast if it's a large `WebView`, and (relatively) slow if it's rather small.

I've tried using an `ObjectAnimator` as well:

```
ObjectAnimator moveInFromBottom = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(webView,
          "translationY", 900f, 0f); 
moveInFromBottom.setDuration(700);
moveInFromBottom.start();
```

This works fine, but there is a **bug** that removes the cursor from an `inputText` in my `WebView`. (Really weird, can't find any info on it). Then I can still type in text in the `inputText`, but I can't remove it using backspace :S

So, my question is: How can I make sure my `Animation` always slides in at the same speed, whatever the height of my `WebView` is?

Comment: *'"100%"* means a percentage relative to itself(so the height will be important here). You probably want `"100%p"` and `0%p` meaning percentages relative to its parent(which I'm assuming has a constant height).

Comment: it does not have a constant height, but I've just solved the problem by creating an TranslateAnimation programmatically and using the screen height, received from the WindowManager